# How to add app icon to project using Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: xcode

How do I add an application icon to my project using Xcode 4.3.1?

Comment: [Drag-n-drop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_and_drop)?

Comment: Apple provides a lot of details here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Drag and drop the icon files you create into Xcode.
They should be named 
Icon.png -- 57x57 for iPhone
Icon@2x.png -- 114x114 retina

Icon-72.png,icon-Small.png and Icon-Small-50.png etc...

then drag them here in Xcode
[image]

Comment: where do you drag the other files ? (Icon-72.png,icon-Small.png and Icon-Small-50.png etc...)

Comment: @DavidBenAri For "Icon-72.png and Icon-72@2x.png" navigate to the screen shown above and scroll down until you see the slots for iPad images, and for Icon-smal-50 etc.. you drag and drop them into your apps bundle and then add them to the iOS 5 Icon files array in your info.plist.

Comment: Regarding where to drag the image files… Apple doc says: `The image files used to represent icons and launch images must all reside in the root level of your bundle.` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW15

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for pointing that out. I'd like to note for anyone reading this that this includes images or resources placed in "groups" in Xcode such as "Supporting Files". Of course stressing that groups and folders are two different things.

Answer (score 4):

You drag and drop the file in from the finder or a location on you're computer to Xcode supporting files. Make sure it is called icon.png and other names for other resolutions / versions etc... 
If it still deosnt come up go to project then target then same drag and drop into the application icon template

Answer (score 3):

Download [Asset Catalog Creator Free](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/asset-catalog-creator-free/id866571115?mt=12) from iTunes. All you have to do is select a base image, and the program will create all required iOS icon sizes for you and place them neatly in an `.xcassets` file, which you can simply drag into Xcode. Much easier than worrying about the sizes/resolutions of individual icons.