# how to create a icon for application in ios?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode4.5, xcode4.3

After creating a basic application , using web view in xcode. 
I need to create a icon for that application.

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.yakshnatechnologies.in/"];
NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
```

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818578/how-to-add-app-icon-to-project-using-xcode-4-3-1

Comment: Which xcode version are you using?

Comment: i am using x code 5.0