# iOS App Icon not appearing on screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

So I have imported the correct sized icons for my app into xCode, and it compiles fine, but when I build and run, I don't see the app icon on my iPhone, it just shows the default 'no icon' icon.

http://prntscr.com/3r99xs - Everything is in there correctly

http://prntscr.com/3r9au6 - What I'm seeing

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong on my end?

Comment: [Possible duplicate of How to add app icon to project using Xcode.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818578/how-to-add-app-icon-to-project-using-xcode-4-3-1)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott the link you referenced is out of date.

Comment: Aah, I see that now. In my defense, I said "Possible"...

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking to the assets folder in your target's general settings? See this link: [Image Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH7-SW1) for Xcode

You'll want to make sure under your Target's Settings (General Tab) that the App Icons are set to use an Asset Catalog, and the correct asset is selected.

Comment: Mine looks different than that. http://prntscr.com/3r9i0e

If I click go on the app icon, it sends me to the image in the OP.

Comment: You're running Xcode 6, which is still currently in development.  Try building and running with Xcode 5.X if you can.  If not, you'll have to wait until Xcode 6 is released to the public to get a clear answer.

Comment: You might also want to try deleting your derived data, making a clean build, and deleting the app from your phone before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on Xcode 5 or 6. Click on the project in XCode go to Info which will show you the plist properties.

Create a new line and start typing Icon files  . It should autocomplete for you but this is exactly the name of it. It is an Array. Under it add the names of your icon files.  You probably have multiple ones. Add them here and they will show up for you. Make sure the image files are added to the project or this wont work.